# Can't Fix Broken Git installation on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I was trying to install git on ubuntu, but there is an error when I try to install or fix broken
git installation.
This is the **error**:

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/lib/git-core/git': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new git package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'git' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'git' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried other possibles solutions, I will list here:

- `apt --fix-broken install`. **Error:** The same problem as above.
- `apt purge git`. Show me to make an `apt fix broken install`
- `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb`. **Error:** `dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'git' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed`
- I tried to remove all files inside `dpkg/updates`, `apt/lists`, `apt/*.bin`, and clen apt-get, to try to force the installation, but again the same error above.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

- I tryed to remove the git `.deb` file from `/var/cache/apt/archives` and install git again, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem with the commands below:

```
sudo apt-mark hold git
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends git
```

And then install `git-core`

```
sudo apt install git-core
```

Comment: This will definitely help future readers.